# What does a sentence/title take (from 'em', 'en', dashes or 'colon') at the end while describing the list or some content?

Tags: colons

I often find it confusing using something at the end of the sentence or title that describes a list or content below it.

The sentence example:

> Here is the list of services we provide **(':', '--' or '-'?)** 
>   [The list of services here]

The title example:

> Enterprise mobility **(':', '--' or '-'?)** 
>   [The enterprise mobility content here]

**Note:** While describing the 'sentence example' and 'title example', I used **colons** above.

Comment: A colon is your best bet, imo. :)

Comment: there is other option: no punctuation

Comment: @Theta30 I may not fully agree with that in case of **sentence** However, it's good escape for **titles**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the primary purposes of colons is to indicate to the reader that what follows either more fully explains a previous thought or, quite specifically, is an enumeration (listing) of related things. See the [usage section on Wikipedia's article on the colon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29#Usage) for more details and examples that at least Wikipedia's community finds acceptable.

As for titles, sometimes you may see an em-dash used to separate a primary title from a subtitle, but generally title and subtitle are separated by a line break (e.g., on the title page of a book) or by a colon (e.g., *The Omnivore’s Dilemma: A Natural History of Four Meals*, taken from [these examples of Chicago-style citation](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html#notes-bibliography-list)).